# How to write LESS selector that targets buttons not disabled?

Tags: css, less

**index.html**:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <button disabled>
      Button 1
    </button>
    <button>
      Button 2
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

**index.less**:

```
:not(&[disabled]) button {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This gives the below output. Both buttons are colored red but I am trying to target only button that is not disabled.
[image]

Is there a way to do this? I am specifically looking to target buttons that are not disabled.

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6gqb19e3/36/

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to style the buttons and simply override the style in the disabled state?

Comment: I was able to come up with this(https://jsfiddle.net/6gqb19e3/72/) after bit of trial and error.

Comment: Use `:disabled`, not `[disabled]`.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to LESS and my syntax was wrong. After bit of trial and error, I came up with this:

```
  button {
    background-color: grey;

    &:not([disabled]) {
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
```

and it gives this output:
[image]

Here is the jsfiddle with: https://jsfiddle.net/6gqb19e3/81/